# How to format JSON data as C# object where object properties are generated dynamically

Tags: c#, json, mailchimp, json-deserialization, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm not sure if my subject is describing my question correctly but hopefully it is.

I'm currently working on a project that requires integration with `Mailchimp` and one of the Member's object property is called the "merge_fields" which returns an `array` of key value pair.

The `Json` data (partial only for simplicity sake) is returned as follows:

```
"members": [{
    "id": "9ff9398a92599aca00401da0fb9f0339da",
"email_address": "myemail@mydomain.com",
"unique_email_id": "90ds8927dae",
"email_type": "html",
"status": "subscribed",
"merge_fields": {
    "FNAME": "My FirstName",
        "LNAME": "My LastName",
        "ADDRESS": "My Address",
        "PHONE": "+555 1234 5678",
        "MMERGE5": ""
},
"stats": {
"avg_open_rate": 0,
"avg_click_rate": 0
},
"ip_signup": "",
"timestamp_signup": "",
...
```

As you can see the "merge_fields" property is an array of key pair values where the key is set dynamically and so is the value but I'm not sure on how to define this in `.NET` so that it can be `deserialized` correctly using `.NET` `NewtonSoft`.

In my Member class, the MergeFields property is defined as follows:

```
[JsonProperty("merge_fields")]
public MailchimpMergeFields MergeFields { get; set; }
```

and my MailchimpMergeFields class is defined as follows:

```
public class MailchimpMergeFields
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An individual merge var and value for a member.
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("merge_fields")]
    public List<KeyValuePair<object, object>> MergeFields { get; set; }

    public MailchimpMergeFields()
    {
        MergeFields = new List<KeyValuePair<object, object>>();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when the data is `deserialized`, it returns 0 element in array of the merge_fields property.

Any idea how I deserialize:

```
"merge_fields": {
    "FNAME": "My FirstName",
    "LNAME": "My LastName",
    "ADDRESS": "My Address",
    "PHONE": "+555 1234 5678",
    "MMERGE5": ""
},
```

to a list of KeyValuePair (or KeyValuePair) and store this in a `.NET` class

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using either a Dictionary<string, string> or dynamic?

Comment: That is not an Array. It is an Object.

Comment: @Flydog57 I've just tried to define it as a Dictionary but it is still returning 0 entries. As for dynamic, I'm not sure how I'd go on defining it? I can defined the property type as dynamic, but if I instantiate it as a dictionary or as a list, it still doesn't return any items.

Comment: @AluanHaddad can you expand? How do I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, ok, I defined my property as an object and its returning some data, so it's in the right track but I'm not sure I like the way it returns it but at least I can investigate and see if I can somehow do something with it. Thanks

Comment: You stated that `merge_fields` is an array of key value pairs but the structure of the example JSON is actually an object. You need to deserialize it into an analogous CLR type. Consider `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This json pattern is easily converted to a dictionary

```
[JsonProperty("merge_fields")]
public Dictionary<string, string> MergeFields { get; set; }
```

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work! I'm going to try to do it directly into my Member class as this may have been my problem all along. I'll get back to you in a sec.

Comment: Yes that worked but I had to define the Dictionary directly into the Member class rather than define in MailchimpMergeFields class as per my original post. Thanks again.